# C# Best Practice - Event subscription

Tags: c#, events

Very basic question, so I'm just looking for a best practice to follow.

My class has a few events which should be subscribed to. (e.g. DiscoveryCompleted). Within the method I do check if the event is null or not, however I'm not sure if I should raise an exception, if so what type. NotImpletementedException?

If the exception is unhandled it doesnt look very elegant.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

My thought is this is precisely what the `NotImplementedException` was created for.  You should never encounter a `NotImplementedException` in production code, but it makes it painfully clear during testing that you have a code path that has, well, not been implemented.

Kinda like a TODO comment, but more in-your-face :)

Although, I might question whether having an event handler that must be subscribed to, and not having a default subscriber, doesn't indicate a design issue.

**EDIT**

I think I misunderstood your initial question slightly, based on your comment.  As others have stated (and I questioned), you should not be throwing an exception when you don't have a subscriber to an event handler; simply don't try to call it.  If no one cares that event x happened, you can't really do anything about that.

It's not your code's responsibility to care whether anyone cares that it happened, but simply to notify them that it happened if they do care.

**EDIT 2 - now with more code**

```
public interface INeedToKnowAboutSomethingImportant 
{
    void WhenSomethingImportantHappens(SomethingImportantHappenedEventArgs args);
}


public class DoesSomethingImportant 
{
    private readonly INeedToKnowAboutSomethingImportant _needyDependency;
    public DoesSomethingImportant(INeedToKnowAboutSomethingImportant needyDependency)
    {
        _needyDependency = needyDependency;
    }

    protected void SomethingImportantHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Handle internally
        _needyDependency.WhenSomethingImportantHappens(new SomethingImportantHappenedEventArgs(e));
    }
}
```

Following this pattern, you don't have to worry about whether anyone is subscribed to your event handlers.  You have to fulfill the dependency, but it doesn't matter *AT ALL* what you fill it with because whatever it is, it will have that method for you to call.

Comment: thanks for your comments. My initial thoughts were that the NotImplementedException could mean that the logic where the method executes has not been implemented (e.g. Discover), and maybe not point to class that called the method (which should have subscribed to the event)

Comment: btw.. what do you mean by having a default subscriber?

Comment: What I mean is that if you're going to throw an exception when an event handler is null, you're for-all-intents-and-purposes requiring it to be subscribed to by something.  If that is the case, you should create at least one handler that subscribes to it initially.  You'll still need to keep the null handling in case the handler list is cleared somehow, but put a default in for the case that no one else actually does care that the handler fired.

Comment: "if you're going to throw an exception when an event handler is null, you're for-all-intents-and-purposes requiring it to be subscribed to by something" - and if that's the case, you shouldn't be using event system in the first place, but rather delegate. Even if it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Sleeper Smith - agreed; I've clarified my response.

Comment: do mind giving a quick example of this? Assuming my methods are Discover, and DiscoveryCompleted. On the completed event all the args come back which may be used by the calling class

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll look into doing things this way. Currently, by way of example, my Discovery method will do a number of things, and at certain points will raise an event (e.g. folder doesnt exist, should it abort or create and continue). So, in this way I rely on the event's feedback to proceed. This does not seem right, but I'm not sure what's the best approach to follow here.

Comment: Events are definitely not the way to handle something that **must be** handled.  The basic pattern I described is called alternately Inversion of Control or Dependency Inversion; it's a pattern that enables testability (among other things), but in this case it helps to ensure that you have concrete implementations for things that must happen.  The other thing I notice is your use of the phrase "event's feedback"; event handlers should not ever feed back to their callers - it's fundamentally a one-way street.

Comment: With a background worker, are you not meant to set the e.Cancel to true in the DoWork method, if you want to cancel. Is this an exception to the general rule? i.e. CancelEventArgs

Comment: To my mind, no, you should not be cancelling the work others are doing in response to an event.  An event is *history*; it has already happened and cannot change.  If you have interdependent processes that must be run e.g. transactionally when an event is fired, then make them explicitly depend on each other.  Don't make your event handler into a workflow provider - it's simply a notification tool.  If you need a workflow provider, the event handler can certainly notify it that an event has taken place.

Answer (score 2):

Events should be optionally subscribed to.
If your class has to call a method, pass a delegate on its constructor instead.

Comment: +1 - good idea! You could also pass the delegate to the relevant method.

Comment: Nice succinct answer. Force the user of your code to do it right n the front end, at compile time, not on the back end at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You should not throw NotImplementedException when you check your event. Just check, and execute if not null.

Take for instance. You put an  element on your page, but you do not intend to implement any events on the button. The button check for Click event, don't find one, and throws NotImplementedException.

Now that is just wrong.

Event is something that's raised when a certain point the program is hit. Then you can have code that is "triggered" by it. The main path of the code should not be affected whether an event is present or not. If the main path of your code cannot continue without the event being triggered, then you need to use a Method instead.

My suggestion is:
1) Create an event.
2) Subscribe the event with handlers that you are going to implement later.
3) Throw the NotImplementedException in the handler.

As for exception is unhandled, you should never be handling NotImplementedException anyway :P... (And you shouldn't be throwing NotImplementedException for null reference to events).

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry about the event object being null. If no one has subscribed to the event then nothing. If you need another function to run outside of your event raising class, then you need to use another pattern besides the observer pattern. As Eduardo suggested you can pass in a delegate, you might also consider a builder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would not throw if an event has no subscribers.

In the "On" method that raises the event you will need a [null test](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/19/why-do-i-need-a-null-test-before-i-invoke-a-delegate.aspx) (note the race condition prevention). Elsewhere your class should not assume that the event has subscribers.